# Call back function not getting current object when calling on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I am learning JS and I came into a point where I kind of can't understand whats happening.

I am calling a `function` on pressing a button but the o/p is saying it is `undefined`. Why am I getting `undefined`? I think I haven't passed the object as a whole so it can't reference from this but when I am trying to print it outside of the `callBack` function of add event listener I am getting the correct O/P.

```
const buttonM = document.getElementById("demo");

let object = {
  name: "Utkarsh",
  surname: "sharma",
  roll: 23,
  objectFunction: function () {
    console.log("Value is :" + this.name + " Surname:" + this.surname);
  },
};

object.objectFunction(); //op: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma (correct op as expected).

buttonM.addEventListener("click", object.objectFunction);  //on pressing the button op:value is:  Surname:Undefined   (expected o/p is: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma).
```

comments are provided with op (output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the `this` reference is different.

When you initially call the `object.objectFunction();` function, your `this` is the object itself, and it has keys for `name` and `surname`.

When you attach the `object.objectFunction` function to the click listener of the button, a reference to the function is created, and you lose the rest of the `object` properties.

Hopefully an example can clear this up:

```js
const buttonM = document.getElementById("demo");

let object = {
  name: "Utkarsh",
  surname: "Sharma",

  objectFunction: function () {
    console.log("this    →", this); // ← I have added this line

    console.log("name    →", this.name)
    console.log("surname →", this.surname)
  },
};

object.objectFunction();
buttonM.addEventListener("click", object.objectFunction);
```

```html
<button id="demo">click</button>
```

Comment: so basically i am passing the function(just function) to the callback. Am i right . @Labu

Comment: Almost! You're passing _a reference_ to (only) the function to the event listener, and the reference is then called when the listener is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `objectFunction` of `object`, it works, as you have already found out. However, when the actual `function` is defined as an event handler, it is no longer bound to object. You can create a function which calls it, like

```
const buttonM = document.getElementById("demo");

let object = {
  name: "Utkarsh",
  surname: "sharma",
  roll: 23,
  objectFunction: function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log("Value is :" + this.name + " Surname:" + this.surname);
  },
};

object.objectFunction(); //op: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma (correct op as expected).

buttonM.addEventListener("click", () => {object.objectFunction()});  //on pressing the button op:value is:  Surname:Undefined   (expected o/p is: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma).
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/561so8e2/

Or you can bind object to the click, as

```
const buttonM = document.getElementById("demo");

let object = {
  name: "Utkarsh",
  surname: "sharma",
  roll: 23,
  objectFunction: function () {
    console.log("Value is :" + this.name + " Surname:" + this.surname);
  },
};

object.objectFunction(); //op: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma (correct op as expected).

buttonM.onclick = object.objectFunction;
buttonM.onclick.bind(object);
//buttonM.addEventListener("click", () => {object.objectFunction()});  //on pressing the button op:value is:  Surname:Undefined   (expected o/p is: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma).
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/561so8e2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the object to the callback it should work

```
   const buttonM = document.getElementById("demo");
let object = {
  name: "Utkarsh",
  surname: "sharma",
  roll: 23,
  objectFunction: function () {
    let self = this;
    console.log("Value is :" + self.name + " Surname:" + self.surname);
  },
};

object.objectFunction(); //op: Value is: Utkarsh  Surname: Sharma (correct op as expected).
buttonM.addEventListener("click",object.objectFunction.bind(object));
```